# Not able to add to array (need to use new keyword) in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, new-operator

I have a property which is an array of items, but when I come to add an item to the array it says I must use the `new` keyword, but I can't use a new keyword with a property.

(`item` is a custom class.)

```
Private itemsvalue As item()
Public Property Items() As item()
    Get
        Return itemsvalue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DBPFindexitem())
        itemsvalue = value
    End Set
End Property

Sub New(ByVal indexbytes As Byte(), ByVal number as integer)

     For count As Integer = 0 To number
        Dim offset As Integer = count * 2 * 4
        Dim xx As New item
        xx.Group = BitConverter.ToInt32(indexbytes, offset + 0)
        xx.ID = BitConverter.ToInt32(indexbytes, offset + 8)
        Items(count) = xx
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I add the `xx` item to the array of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a collection instead of an array.
A Collection will automatically resize to hold as many items as you put into it.

For example:

```
Private itemsvalue As New List(Of item)
Public Property Items() As List(Of item)
    Get
        Return itemsvalue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of item))
        itemsvalue = value
    End Set
End Property

Sub New(ByVal indexbytes As Byte(), ByVal number as integer)
     For count As Integer = 0 To number
        Dim offset As Integer = count * 2 * 4
        Dim xx As New item
        xx.Group = BitConverter.ToInt32(indexbytes, offset + 0)
        xx.ID = BitConverter.ToInt32(indexbytes, offset + 8)
        Items.Add(xx)    
    Next
End Sub
```

If you're writing a public library, you should use a [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of item)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) instead.  This will allow you to replace it later with an inherited collection with special behavior, without breaking existing clients.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx).

If you don't want other people to modify the collection, you should expose a 
[`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of item)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

---

If you really want to use an array, you should initialize the array, like this:

```
Items = New item(number)
```

Comment: Yours wouldn't work either, you need New(), but you fixed it while I was fixing mine. ;)  I like your solution better anyway, he really ought to be using a collection. Also, you're using C# syntax, VB.NET uses `(Of T)` rather than `<T>`.

Comment: Sorry so there are collections, lists and arrays? What are the diffrences

Comment: `Collection` and `List` are two different classes.  `Collection` is more extensible, allowing you to customize its behavior.

Comment: Arrays cannot be resized in-place.

Comment: For more information, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1ad18x6.aspx or here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/9439eda3-be67-4123-8fa5-e58828d89b15

Answer (score 2):

One more thing: unless you want to be able to replace the whole `Items` collection with another one, you might want to get rid of the setter and make `Items` read-only:

```
Private itemsvalue As New List(Of item)

Public ReadOnly Property Items() As List(Of item)
    Get
        Return itemsvalue
    End Get
End Property
```

This way, `Items` is initially an empty list and cannot be changed to another collection. If you need a fresh start with it, you call `Items.Clear()`.

(This suggestion is from the .NET Framework Design Guidelines btw.)

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the private array, but you never instantiated it.

In VB.NET, arrays are objects.

```
Private itemsvalue As New item(numItems)
```

That's where the "new" goes... also, you'll need to provide some bounds for that array, which is why it's better to use generic `List<Item>` rather than an array, as another person suggested, but you still have to instantiate the list.

```
Private itemsvalue As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Item)
```

Then you can call itemsvalue.Add(myitem) as many times as necessary without worrying about array bounds.

Comment: I can't specify a size because any number of items may be added to the array later. Would a collection be better?

Comment: Yes, it would be much better.  See my answer.

Comment: So what are the differences between lists, arrays and collections